# Can inotify allow me to monitor all files with a specific name extension no matter where they are on disk?

Tags: linux, inotify

Can inotify allow me to monitor all files with a specific name extension no matter where they are on disk?
For example, if I want to monitor all *.mp3 files on my device in various directories. Is it possible?

Many thanks!
Amanda

Answer (score 1):

Not without setting up notification for every single directory. Consider using the auditing subsystem instead.

Answer (score 0):

With pyinotify at least you could. You'd have to watch recursively at `/` or the directory your disk is mounted on and use the `exclude_filter` argument to the `WatchManager.add_watch` method.
Maybe react https://github.com/copton/react already does all you need.